# executing wsadmin script from (inside) powershell script

Tags: powershell, scripting, jython, wsadmin

How to execute a simple wsadmin script (using wsadmin.bat) from powershell script. Please help me.

Example wsadmin action -> AdminControl.invoke(cluster, 'stop')

Thanks,
Kumar.